# unrecognised command line option '-m64' in NVIDIA Jetson TX2

Tags: linux, makefile, nvidia-jetson

I am using an NVIDIA Jetson TX2. I am trying to generate an ".so" file using "make" for the DynamixelSDK. But I am getting this Error:

```
mkdir -p ./.objects/
gcc -O2 -O3 -DLINUX -D_GNU_SOURCE -Wall -c -I../../include/dynamixel_sdk -m64 -fPIC -g -c ../../src/dynamixel_sdk/group_bulk_read.c -o .objects/group_bulk_read.o
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-m64’
Makefile:114: recipe for target '.objects/group_bulk_read.o' failed
make: *** [.objects/group_bulk_read.o] Error 1
```

You can access the make file at- https://pastebin.com/zz9MNnqp

Here's a part of the MakeFile :

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# C COMPILER, COMPILER FLAGS, AND TARGET PROGRAM NAME
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
DIR_DXL     = ../..
DIR_OBJS    = ./.objects

INSTALL_ROOT = /usr/local

MAJ_VERSION = 2
MIN_VERSION = 0
REV_VERSION = 0

TARGET      = libdxl_x64_c.so
TARGET1     = $(TARGET).$(MAJ_VERSION)
TARGET2     = $(TARGET).$(MAJ_VERSION).$(MIN_VERSION)
TARGET3     = $(TARGET).$(MAJ_VERSION).$(MIN_VERSION).$(REV_VERSION)

CHK_DIR_EXISTS = test -d
PRINT       = echo
STRIP       = strip
AR          = ar
ARFLAGS     = cr
LD          = g++
LDFLAGS     = -shared -fPIC $(FORMAT)#-Wl,-soname,dxl
LD_CONFIG   = ldconfig
CP          = cp
CP_ALL      = cp -r
RM          = rm
RM_ALL      = rm -rf
SYMLINK     = ln -s
MKDIR       = mkdir
CC          = gcc
CX          = g++
CCFLAGS     = -O2 -O3 -DLINUX -D_GNU_SOURCE -Wall -c $(INCLUDES) $(FORMAT) -fPIC -g
CXFLAGS     = -O2 -O3 -DLINUX -D_GNU_SOURCE -Wall -c $(INCLUDES) $(FORMAT) -fPIC -g
FORMAT     = -m64
INCLUDES    += -I$(DIR_DXL)/include/dynamixel_sdk
 #---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Tried Both the 32 and 64 bit Versions of the MakeFile (for linux).

I don't know hoe to solve this error. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error usually arises when the `march`, that is, the architecture of the target machine is not defined correctly. The `-m64` line represents that it is being compiled for a 64bit architecture. If you see the Makefile for 32bit, it would be `-m32`.

Try changing the makefile such that it reads something like :

```
...

FORMAT     = -march=armv8-a+crypto -mcpu=cortex-a57+crypto

....
```

This is march is usually used for Jetson TX2.

Also, for TX2, GCC options to keep in mind are :

- Use latest GCC toolchain 7.2
- Use CLANG llvm front end an alternative to GCC
- -march=armv8.a+crypto+simd, this enables SIMD, crypto and floating point instruction set and may help.

Answer (score 1):

The makefile assumes that the target is the x86-64 architecture.  As a first step, you can simply remove the `-m64` option from the `FORMAT` line in order to get further in the build.  However, if the project has never been ported to another architecture, there could well be other target dependencies.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Which part? Have you tried removing the `-m64` option from the `FORMAT` line?

Comment: Thanks for our help. The answer did somewhat help, so +1